# Hwy the Subnet is not getting created while CIDRR it is showing in VPC dashboard using terraform script?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

Recently I have started exploring terraform script.  I am trying to create  subnet, VPC, Internet gateway, route table, route table association. I am getting an error message.

```
Error: error creating EC2 Subnet: InvalidVpcID.NotFound: The vpc ID '10.0.0.0/16' does not exist
 │       status code: 400, request id: ee23c9be-75fd-4a8e-a7c0-fb63bd454ce4
 │
 │   with aws_subnet.main[3],
 │   on temp2.tf line 8, in resource "aws_subnet" "main":
 │    8: resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
```

The terraform script I am using :-
Script_1

```
resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
   count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names)}"                   
   vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.example.cidr_block}"              
   cidr_block = "${cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.example.cidr_block, 8 , count.index)}"             
   availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names[count.index]}"             
   tags = {
      Name = "Public_Subnet_${count.index + 1}"                                              
          }
   }
 resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_rtable" 
{                                    
 count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names)}"  
 subnet_id      = "${aws_subnet.main.*.vpc_id[count.index]}"  
 route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.rtable.vpc_id}"                                        
 }
 resource "aws_route_table" "rtable" 
 {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.example.id
  route {                                                 
   cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"                              
   gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.igw.vpc_id            
    }
  tags = {
  Name = "Internet_Gateway"
  }
 }
 resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" 
   {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.example.id}"
    tags = {
      Name = "My Internet gateway"
    }
}
```

Script_2

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}
resource "aws_vpc" "example" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}
```

Script_3

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "azs" 
{

}
```

Comment: `vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.example.cidr_block}"` does not work. Should be `vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.example.id}"` or just `vpc_id = aws_vpc.example.id`

Comment: it is Just interpolation. I am getting the same error, after applying those as well.

Comment: No, you write `.cidr_block`, I write `.id`.

Comment: Great it worked. May I know the reason for using ".id"  ?

Comment: You want the thing that identifes the vpc (it's id), use `.id`. You want the cidr block of the vpc, use `.cidr_block`.